# glTexImage2D: Generic InternalFormat

Tags: opengl

The documentation of [glTexImage2D](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glTexImage2D.xml) for *internalformat* states, that it may be 1, 2, 3, or 4 to specify the number of components. Does this only apply to 'color'-textures or could I pass 1 instead of GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT and subsequently use it as a depth buffer target?

Comment: Note, that you cited the OpenGL 2.1 documentation which is rather outdated. Starting from 3.3 Core Profile (around 2010), numbers are no longer valid for the internal format and only symbolic constants may be used as given [here](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/).

Comment: ah, thanks for clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use generic numbers (which you should *never* do. Always use internal formats with explicit sizes), then you will get a color image format with at least as many channels as you ask for.